# configuration for node.js + express for large queue of incoming requests

Tags: node.js, express

I have a specific/strange requirement where I need to do something like this:

```
app.put('/example/:entity', function(req, res, next) {
     fs.writeFileSync(someFile);
});
```

Since its a `sync` operation, it will block the event loop and I am concerned that node.js/express will start dropping http requests.

For a short term solution:

- Is there any queue/limit of incoming requests in node.js/express?
- Is there any configuration that I can use to increase the queue size?
- Would node.js/express bounce requests if the event loop is blocked?

Comment: you have a requirement to do synchronous file writes?

Comment: yes....for now I have to do this. its a very simple opeation of reading and writing file back...thats all this server does

Comment: What i can say is that Node will not drop requests if the thread is busy serving another request ( that's the point of the event system )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your *service* will still accept incoming connections while you have node's event loop blocked up but *express* *won't be able to respond* to anything. Incoming requests will get queued as part of the underlying TCP implementation.

> Is there any queue/limit of incoming requests in node.js/express?

There's probably a virtual limit in terms of memory being used to queue incoming requests, but this is a detail of your underlying TCP stack, not node.js.

> Is there any configuration that I can use to increase the queue size?

I think you can decerase the TCP connection cap in OS settings to prevent your server from getting easily overloaded. Increasing it is the wrong solution to your problem I think (see below).

> Would node.js/express bounce requests if the event loop is blocked?

No, since its I/O under the hood, node.js/express are not bouncing the incoming requets you get while the event loop is blocked. Your requests won't get bounced until you hit some configured TCP connection limit. But you really don't want it to ever get this blocked up.

To be frank, blocking the event loop in node.js is almost always a bad idea. and there's always a way around it. In your case, if you need to write that file in series, try pushing events onto a backend queue that you can configure to handle one event at a time without blocking up the works. [kue + redis](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) is a good option for this.